# GCC compiling multiple files in different folders

Tags: c, gcc

I am searching for gcc command that can compile multiple files in different folders at a time. prg1.c prg1.h are in C:\folder.
prg2.c which is in c:/folder/sub  includes "prg1.h"

So, I need to compile prg1.c and prg2.c at atime... and need to save generated .exe in c:/folder/sub

I am trying

```
cd C:\folder
gcc -o ../../sub/prg2.exe  prg1.c ../../sub/prg2.c
```

but getting no such file or directory error

I even tried with full path ...

Somebody help me with exact command

Comment: can you give us the arborescence of your project ? and from which folder do you launch the command ?

Comment: Hi @georges command launch can be done from anywhere I like (Depending on your Suggestion). Thanks for response ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dropping off the top of the windows file system with `../../`, perhaps that is the problem? try

```
gcc -o sub/prg2.exe  prg1.c sub/prg2.c
```

Comment: hi @Karthik T Thanks for quick response    may I know how to include prg1.h(in /folder) into prg2.h  (in /folder/sub)